# Mixing JSF Tag and HTML

Tags: jsf-2

I just started out using JSF 2.0 but I found myself mixing JSF tags with standard HTML tag
to achieve the desired layout.
Although I am using the facelets to layout my pages, but I think I cant help but mix components.

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{myBean.handleSearch}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="Reset" action="#{myBean.handleReset}"/>
        <div>
            <!-- Some JSF component -->
        </div>
```

I have been thinking if I have been running into bad practice.  Any source of info for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not a bad practice. This is perfectly fine. The only reason to use a JSF component is to have access to it in the JSF component tree. It would be a more poor practice to use `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` instead of `<div>` here. But if it was a container of which you'd like to ajax-update its content, then a `<h:panelGroup id="foo" layout="block">` would have been perfectly fine as would an 'html5-friendly' `<div jsf:id="foo">` with the `xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"` namespace.

For a bit of history, you may find this useful: [JSF vs HTML(JSP) for enterprise portals UI layer. Which one to Choose? and WHY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273595/jsf-vs-htmljsp-for-enterprise-portals-ui-layer-which-one-to-choose-and-why)