# Attribute align invalid for tag panelGrid according to TLD

Tags: jsf, tld

i have developed application with following facets

- Dynamic Web Module 2.5
- JavaServer Faces 1.2
- Java 5

and i m using Rich Faces 3.2, Sever is Tomcat 6

i get an error

```
Attribute align invalid for tag panelGrid according to TLD.
```

i did followed the link
 [Layout out invalid according to TLD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730744/the-layout-attribute-is-invalid-according-to-the-specified-tld)

but it didnt solve my problem since i m already using JSF 1.2. What could be the possible cause of this error. I can give following hints

- the project was initially developed with no JavaServer Facet installed
- i add JSF 1.2 and Rich faces (for some enhancement that i needed to be incorporated).
- ever since then i started getting this error.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other question is irrelevant. It's about the `layout` attribute while you're attempting to use the `align` attribute. The `layout` attribute of `<h:panelGrid>` was introduced in JSF 1.2. The `align` attribute was never supported by `<h:panelGrid>`. This attribute is not listed among the supported attributes of the `<h:panelGrid>` tag for JSF 1.2, as per [its TLD documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/h/panelGrid.html).

So, **remove** that `align` attribute and do whatever you're trying to do using CSS instead.