# Why do we need JSF tags , If we have HTML tags

Tags: java, html, jsf, user-interface

JSF is a  MVC Framework,but I am confused why we need JSF tags If we already have so many HTML tags.
No doubt JSF has simplified lot of things. 
I would like to know more about what exactly is Model View and Controller in JSF.

Comment: JSF is used for `View` purpose out of MVC

Comment: This one might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273595/jsf-vs-htmljsp-for-enterprise-portals-ui-layer-which-one-to-choose-and-why

Comment: Because JSF developers don't want to redefine the meaning of HTML tags.

Comment: There are several questions here on SO that should help answer your question: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972221/give-me-a-jsf-2-0-tutorial) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111387/understanding-jsf-as-a-mvc-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF is a component based MVC framework which is built on top of the Servlet API and provides components in favor of taglibs, which can be used in JSP or any other Java based view technology such as Facelets. Facelets is much more suited to JSF than JSP. It namely provides great templating capabilities such as composite components, while JSP basically only offers the  for templating, so that you're forced to create custom components with raw Java code (which is a bit opaque and a lot of tedious work in JSF) when you want to replace a repeated group of components with a single component. If you can, I recommend to drop JSP and go for Facelets when you want to develop with JSF.

As being a MVC (Model-View-Controller) framework, JSF provides the FacesServlet as the sole request-response Controller. It takes all the standard and tedious HTTP request/response work from your hands, such as gathering user input, validating/converting them, putting them in model objects, invoking actions and rendering the response. This way you end up with basically a JSP or Facelets (XHTML) page for View and a Javabean class as Model. The JSF components are been used to bind the view with the model (such as your ASP.NET web control does) and the FacesServlet uses the JSF component tree to do all the work.